# Passing ko.mapping.toJSON data to WCF results in null variable

Tags: json, wcf, knockout.js

Is it ok to pass strings like this to a WCF service:

```
self.savePreferences = function(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "services/Foo.svc/SavePreferences",
            type: 'POST',
            timeout: 3000,
            data: ko.mapping.toJSON(self.user().preferences),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    alert("data saved " + result);
                } else {
                    //todo, send server email alert
                    alert("Something went wrong. We will look into it.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

in this case I always get null for jsonPreferences in my service

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
      Method = "POST", 
      RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string SavePreferences(string jsonPreferences);
```

or do I need to do this:

data: JSON.stringify(ko.mapping.toJSON(self.user().preferences))

Comment: What do you except to have in your `jsonPreferences` parameter in your `SavePreferences` method? Some JS object as a JSON string?

Comment: @nemesv I thought ko.mapping.toJSON would have taken care of that for me but obviously the many "." are causing issues..

Comment: @nemesv   I'm passing it via post like this {"AppStart":true,"DateFormat":"YYYY-MM-DD"}